# How to show initial value in brackets when observable is edited in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knock out js. I have requirement like, a textbox is bind to an observable which is populated from either database are from computed observable on initial load. When user changes the initial value in this text box, I need to display the change as "current value(original value)" along with color change of the textbox.

How this can be achieved in knockout js. Can anyone give some idea?

Comment: I would either create a custom viewmodel for this, or create an extension to an observable that keeps track of orginal value

Answer (score 0):

I think using a computed observable with a custom read and write may do the trick.

```
this.display = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this.updatedVal() + "(" + this.orginalVal() + ")";
        },
        write: function (value) {
            this.updatedVal(value);
        },
        owner: this
    });
```